# How is "Native" status determined for the US DV lottery?

Tags: usa, immigration, greencard

I'm curious about how "Native" status is determined for the purposes of the US DV.  Assume the person in question was born in Kuwait, but has Pakistani citizenship / passport, and has been working for the last 15 years Kuwait (never changing to Kuwaiti citizenship).

The DV lottery seems to focus on "Native" status.  Since 2002, natives of Pakistan are forbidden from receiving visas through the US Diversity Immigration Lottery [ref [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_Immigrant_Visa#Ineligible_countries)].  Will birth location (and not the country of their passport) allow someone in this situation to apply for the DV lottery?

Comment: Is there any context in which "native" is determined by anything *other* than place of birth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Native, in this context, means your original place of birth. It doesn't matter what citizenship you have or where you live.

Thus if the DV recipient was born in Kuwait, he is eligible for DV; however, if he was born in Pakistan, he would not be eligible.

Comment: @MikePennington married to a Kuwaiti? Or telling things that are not true? They do ask for birth certificate, it's not that they take your word for it.

Comment: @MikePennington another possibility is that the person in question came to the US through some means other than the DV program.  What do you know about his immigration status in the US?